# Input string was wrong

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, json, string

I got an error **Input string was not in correct format**

here is my string

```
string requestData = string.Format("{\"api_version\":{0},\"method\":\"{1}\",\"merchant_account\":\"{2}\",\"merchant_password\":\"{3}\",\"transaction_unique_id\":\"{4}\",\"amount\":{5},\"currency\":\"{6}\",\"callback_url\":\"{7}\",\"user_id\":\"{8}\",\"user_ip\":\"{9}\",\"user_email\":\"{10}\",\"card\":{\"card_number\":\"{11}\"}", apiVersion, method, merchantAccount, merchantPassword, transactionId, amount, currency, callbackUrl, id, ip, mail, cardNumber);
```

all variables are strings there is not type casting.What is wrong with this code?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

you need to escape the `{` symbols using `string.Format()`:
    instead of `{` use `{{`
    instead of `}` use `}}`

Note: This applies to the `{` symbols that you want to appear in the resulting string.

Also, if you're trying to create JSON, I'd highly recommend using JSON.Net and `Serialize<>` instead of doing it by hand like this.

Answer (score 2):

You can also use String interpolation this feature is available in C# 6 and later versions

```
string requestData = $"{{\"api_version\":{apiVersion},\"method\":\"{method}\",\"merchant_account\":\"{merchantAccount}\",\"merchant_password\":\"{merchantPassword}\",\"transaction_unique_id\":\"{transactionId}\",\"amount\":{amount},\"currency\":\"{currency}\",\"callback_url\":\"{callbackUrl}\",\"user_id\":\"{id}\",\"user_ip\":\"{ip}\",\"user_email\":\"{mail}\",\"card\":{{\"card_number\":\"{cardNumber}\"}}";
```

Comment: How to add one more closed bracket '}' in the end?due to the that missing bracket in the end  i have got wrong json fromat

Comment: You need to add one more }(bracket)

Comment: So i did. And i have got another error saying that a character '}' must be escaped by doubling in interpolated string,

Comment: actually you need to add two }} bracket

Answer (score 1):

If every expected parameter is a string, api version missed quotes!

```
string requestData = string.Format("{{\"api_version\":\"{0}\",\"method\":\"{1}\",\"merchant_account\":\"{2}\",\"merchant_password\":\"{3}\",\"transaction_unique_id\":\"{4}\",\"amount\":{5},\"currency\":\"{6}\",\"callback_url\":\"{7}\",\"user_id\":\"{8}\",\"user_ip\":\"{9}\",\"user_email\":\"{10}\",\"card\":{{\"card_number\":\"{11}\"}}}}", apiVersion, method, merchantAccount, merchantPassword, transactionId, amount, currency, callbackUrl, id, ip, mail, cardNumber);
```

**Edit: I didn't notice the missing double {}, when you use string format you must double every `{` or `}` to escape it**